# How do I convert an address back to a range in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, range

I have an input box that asks the user to select a cell, storing this as a range.
Then, this range will be converted to an address (string) so the !worksheet isn't also saved.

A For loop will cycle through the worksheets, however, I need to reference the start cell (range) to run a macro - the problem is, I cannot reference the start cell any longer, as this is now String, not a range.

I need to re-convert the address (string) back to a range, within the For loop.

```
Set myCell = Application.InputBox( _
    prompt:="Select a cell", Type:=8)
    
celladdress = myCell.Address()
    
NoSheets = Sheets.Count

For x = 2 To NoSheets

'covert address back to range

'Identify blend data
NumRows = Range(myCell, myCell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
NumColumns = Range(myCell, myCell.Offset(0, 1).End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count

Set StartRange = Range(myCell, myCell.Offset(NumRows - 1, NumColumns - 1))
StartRange.Copy
```

Comment: `Range(celladdress)`

Comment: Careful here, unqualified `Range` calls are implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is.. you'll want a `Worksheet` object in that loop to properly qualify `Range` calls. Consider using `For Each` to iterate the workbook's `Worksheets` collection: it'll loop faster and you'll get that `Worksheet` reference for free, plus your code will still work if the sheet at index 1 is ever moved elsewhere.

Comment: Then use `currentSheet.Cells(myCell.Row, myCell.Column)` to get the cell at the address of `myCell` but on the `currentSheet` - you rarely ever really need to mess around with string addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `Worksheet` object reference inside that loop:

```
For x = 2 To NoSheets
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Set currentSheet = thatWorkbook.Worksheets(x)
    ...
Next
```

Once you have the sheet, you can still use `myCell` to get a `Range` on the `currentSheet`, without dealing with cell address strings:

```
Set currentCell = currentSheet.Cells(myCell.Row, myCell.Column)
```

Avoid unqualified calls to `Range` and `Cells`; they're implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet`, which typically means code that only works with `Worksheet.Activate` calls sprinkled through (you generally want to avoid having to use `Select` and `Activate` altogether).

Answer (score 0):

myCell.address(,,,true) gives you the full external address of the range.

myCell.Parent.Name gives you the name of the worksheet

Comment: I don't want to reference the worksheet, that's why I converted the myCell to cellAddress, so it stops the reference of the specific worksheet

Comment: Just fully qualify the Range by telling it which sheet you want
For Each oSht in worksheets
msgbox oSht.range(celladdress).address(,,,true)
next oSht